# Why is this invalid syntax? (Class function)

Tags: python, class

The code I am trying to enter (python) looks like this:

```
class RainfallTable:
    def _init_ (self, njrainfall.txt):
        self.njrainfall.txt = open(njrainfall.txt, 'r')
    def close(self):
        if self.t:
            self.t.close()
            self.t = None
```

I am trying to get this class to simply open a file called njrainfall.txt, but I get the following error message when I do so:

```
  File "3Homework.py", line 2
def _init_ (self, njrainfall.txt):
                            ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `__init__`, double underscore. Another thing, no `.` in variable names, in your file

Comment: I added it in, but it is still saying there is an error, returning the same message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a `.` in your variable names, which is invalid syntax for python. Remove those in your `njrainfall.txt` variables. A good substitute would be `njrainfall_file` or something similar. Secondly, the init functions is written with two underscores, like so:

```
def __init__(self, njrainfall_file):
```

Here some code:

```
class RainfallTable:
    def __init__(self, njrainfall_file):
        self.njrainfall_file = open(njrainfall_file, 'r')
    def close(self):
        if self.t:
            self.t.close()
            self.t = None
```

Make sure to pass `njrainfall_file` as a string of filename!

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I'll accept the answer once Stackoverflow allows me to. Much appreciated

Comment: @Matt No problem, remember to read the error message carefully and check for syntax errors!

Answer (score 0):

Function/constructor should have only variables as input

You can pass text file name along with path to that init function

Better you pass text file with absolute path

```
class RainfallTable:
    def _init_ (self, textfile):
        self.t = open(textfile, 'r')
    def close(self):
        if self.t:
            self.t.close()
            self.t = None
```

Call it as `RainfallTable('njrainfall.txt')`

Comment: With that suggestion it looks like this:  class RainfallTable:
 'def __init__ (self, njrainfall.txt):
  self.fh = open(njrainfall.txt)
 def close(self):
  if self.t:
   self.t.close()
   self.t = None'

Same error though

Comment: Do not put text file name as variable, instead pass a text file to that function

Comment: I believe the filename should be passed as a string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confused with strings, parameter/variable names, and class objects.

The dot you are using in what must be a variable name (`njrainfall.txt`) looks like either a string with an actual file name, or an object attribute.

As other people have pointed out already, you shall not use a dot in a variable / parameter name.

You should instead do use (I have added a try..except to handle the case in which the passed filename does not exist):

```
class RainfallTable:
  def _init_ (self, sRainFallFilename):
    try:
      self.rainfallFile = open(sRainFallFilename, 'r')
    except:
      self.rainfallFile = None
      print "file %s does not exist" % sRainFallFilename

  def close(self):
    if not self.rainfallFile == None :
        self.rainfallFile.close()
        self.rainfallFile = None
```

Notice I have also changed the close() method to use the same attribute as in init()

Then you can call the class like:

```
RainFallTable myRainFallTable( "NJ.txt" )
...
myRainFallTable.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fullstop here

```
self.njrainfall.txt
```

to something else.

Like

```
self.njrainfall
```